# Element-wise mean of several big.matrix objects in R

Tags: r, bigdata, r-bigmemory

I have 17 filebacked big.matrix objects (dim 10985 x 52598, 4.3GB each) of which I would like to calculate the element-wise mean. The result can be stored in another big.matrix (gcm.res.outputM).

biganalytics::apply() doesn't work as the MARGIN can be set to 1 OR 2 only. I tried to use 2 for loops as shown here

```
gcm.res.outputM <- filebacked.big.matrix(10958, 52598, separated = FALSE, backingfile = "gcm.res.outputM.bin", backingpath = NULL, descriptorfile = "gcm.res.outputM.desc", binarydescriptor = FALSE)

for(i in 1:10958){
   for(j in 1:52598){
    t <- rbind(gcm.res.output1[i,j], gcm.res.output2[i,j],gcm.res.output3[i,j], gcm.res.output4[i,j],
           gcm.res.output5[i,j], gcm.res.output6[i,j],gcm.res.output7[i,j], gcm.res.output8[i,j],
           gcm.res.output9[i,j], gcm.res.output10[i,j],gcm.res.output11[i,j], gcm.res.output12[i,j],
           gcm.res.output13[i,j], gcm.res.output14[i,j],gcm.res.output15[i,j], gcm.res.output16[i,j],
           gcm.res.output17[i,j])
    tM <- apply(t, 2, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
    gcm.res.outputM[i,j] <- tM
    }
}
```

which will take around 1.5 minutes per row i and thus about 11 days run.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to speed up this calculation? I'm using a 64x Windows10 machine with 16GB of RAM.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this http://winvector.github.io/Accumulation/. Using `data.table` package will probably help

Comment: There are many ways to do that. You could implement that in Rcpp, or use an R function on blocks of columns of all matrices, or add the matrices one by one. These solutions are a trade-off between easiness of implementation, how fast it is and how much memory it uses.

How much RAM do you have?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @F Privé, I have 16GB of RAM. The advantage of working with the big.matrix objects is that I don't have to load the entire matrices directly into the RAM. What I could do is make the above calculation on an entire row of values at the time and therefore get rid of the second for loop. If you have any more suggestions I'd be happy to hear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this Rcpp code:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH, bigmemory, RcppEigen)]]
#include <bigmemory/MatrixAccessor.hpp>
#include <RcppEigen.h>
using namespace Eigen;
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void add_to(XPtr<BigMatrix> xptr_from, XPtr<BigMatrix> xptr_to) {

  Map<MatrixXd> bm_from((double *)xptr_from->matrix(),
                        xptr_from->nrow(), xptr_from->ncol());
  Map<MatrixXd> bm_to((double *)xptr_to->matrix(),
                      xptr_to->nrow(), xptr_to->ncol());

  bm_to += bm_from;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void div_by(XPtr<BigMatrix> xptr, double val) {

  Map<MatrixXd> bm((double *)xptr->matrix(),
                   xptr->nrow(), xptr->ncol());

  bm /= val;
}
```

Then if you have a list of big.matrix objects of the same size, you can do:

```
library(bigmemory)
bm_list <- lapply(1:5, function(i) big.matrix(1000, 500, init = i))
res <- deepcopy(bm_list[[1]])
lapply(bm_list[-1], function(bm) add_to(bm@address, res@address))
res[1:5, 1:5]  # verif
div_by(res@address, length(bm_list))
res[1:5, 1:5]  # verif
```

Comment: The above code is really helpful but I'm struggling to use it when NA values are present. Can I include something similar to 'na.rm = TRUE' in Rcpp?

Comment: I think you won't be able to use (or adapt) this code with missing values. Please ask another question specific to your new problem.